# dynamic_cast does not behave the way it should with APP_STL := gnustl_static

Tags: c++, android-ndk, dynamic-cast

I have a simple c++ class called Square that inherits from Comparable (an interface with a function compareTo).

Here's the c++ implementation of the compareTo method :

```
int Square::compareTo(Comparable* c, char criteria) {

    if (dynamic_cast<Square*>(c) != NULL) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

I generated the libray (.so file) with Android-ndk (r8c). Find below the code of Android.mk and Application.mk

Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := testinterface
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wrappers.cpp Shape.cpp Square.cpp Circle.cpp
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += rtti
//LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -frtti           -> The commented lines were tests
//LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
//LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk :

```
//APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti -> That was for a test but it didn't work either
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

And here's the Java code I use to call the function compareTo (I used SWIG to generates the Java wrappers) :

```
Square s = new Square(10);
Square s3 = new Square(10);
outputText.append("s.compareTo(s3) ? " + s.compareTo(new Comparable(Square.getCPtr(s3), false), 'c') +"\n");
```

The result shows 4, in regards to the c++ code that means s3 is not a Square. The problem is that if I change `APP_STL := gnustl_static` to `APP_STL  := stlport_static` in the Application.mk file the result is 2.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: You should make your non-leaf classes abstract, then you will spot your mistake by yourself.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I don't think it's a mistake because if I change one line in the Application.mk the result is different (for the same c++ and Java code).

Comment: `new Comparable` should not make sense, because it doesn't. `Comparable` should be abstract.

Comment: It's abstract in c++. In c++ Square inherits from Shape and Comparable (it's for test purpose only, I know it's not a good implementation), and in Java multiple inheritance doesn't exist so my workaround with SWIG is the following : instanciate a Square in Java (which behind in c++ is a Square and a Comparable) and create a Comparable (in Java) with a pointer to the c++ square  with `Square.getCPtr(s3)`. So in Java we have 2 objects and each have a pointer to the real c++ object.

Comment: I know what you're thinking. I'm just telling you that C++ doesn't work like that :-)

Comment: Actually I compiled and ran my code on c++ and it worked so I don't see why the problem would be in the c++ code

Comment: Well, just because it compiles doesn't mean it is what you want :-) `new Comparable` actually creates a `Comparable` instance, and *not* a `Square` instance...

Comment: Yes but behind it's the same object, the constructor in Java (generated with SWIG) is the following : `protected Square(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn)` and it links the Comparable object to the actual Square, so this Comparable is a Square (2 pointers on the same object)

Answer (score 0):

Are the constructor and the `dynmic_cast` in different shared
objects?  And if so, what were the options passed to `dlopen`?
If the shared objects are loaded with `RTLD_LOCAL`, then g++
will consider the type `Square` in one to be unrelated to the
type `Square` in the other, so the `dynamic_cast` will fail.

If you're not calling `dlopen` explicitly, then the implicit
load will use the flags used to load the shared object which
needs your shared objects.  When Java loads a shared object, it
uses `RTLD_LOCAL`, which means any other shared objects
implicitly loaded by that shared object will also use 
`RTLD_LOCAL`.  In our case, we created a small front end shared
object, which did nothing other than load all of the shared
objects we needed, *in an order determined by the dependencies*,
so that there would be no implict loading, and we could control
absolutely the arguments to `dlopen`.  We did this by deriving
all of the Java classes which called into our library from
a common base class which contained something like:

```
//  In the Java base class...
private static native void initializeLibrary();

static
{
    System.loadLibrary("WrapperLibrary");
    initializeLibrary();
}
```

The `initializeLibrary()` function then did the sequence of
explicit `dlopen`, in the dependency determined order.

Comment: What do you mean by shared object ? Do you need more of my c++ source ? I don't use dlopen what does it have to do with this ? I'm sorry but I can't really understand what you mean here, I think the problem is in Android.mk or Application.mk file because everything works as it should if I change one line. I would use this solution but I need the exceptions as well so I need to use gnustl_static (see CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html inside Android-ndk folder)

Comment: A shared object is your .so file.  If you have more than one .so file, then you probably _need_ to use `dlopen` explicitly, so that you can control its options.  (If you have a .so file, you _are_ using `dlopen`, whether explicitly or not.  It's the only way you can load a .so file and execute in it under Unix.)

Comment: I have only one so file under my libs folder. It was generated with Android-ndk command `ndk-build`. So the problem is not here ?

Comment: @Fr4nz Unless you're building more than one .so, this should not be a problem.  On the other hand, in the test you show, you pass a new `Comparable` to the function, so it is _not_ a `Square` (supposing that `Square` derives from `Comparable`, and not vice versa).  But I'd have to see more of the Java code to be sure, and even then, I don't know off hand how swig maps the Java types to C++.

Comment: It's mapped with pointers. Behind the Java code there's two c++ instance of Square (s and s3). I instanciate in Java a Comparable but behind it's just a c++ pointer to the instance of s3 so I can use it with compareTo. I think it's more a problem with the runtime gnustl_static because it behave differently than if I use it with the runtime stlport_static

Comment: @Fr4nz I know the general philosophy behind swig, and I know how swig maps C++ classes to Java classes.  I don't know exactly how the mappings are implemented in this case.  If it is done correctly, the last line of your code above should print 4; if you implement the compare function in Java, that's what it will print.

Comment: But can you explain why I got 2 when I use the runtime stlport_static and I got 4 when I use the runtime gnustl_static ?

Comment: @Fr4nz No, but I suspect that you didn't actually test the same code.

Comment: I only changed the line I told you in Application.mk, that's why I'm so confused...

Comment: @Fr4nz: have you tried the two runtimes for Comparable objects that only exist on the C++ side?

Comment: @AlexCohn: what do you mean ? How could I do that ?

Comment: I mean, to call `compareTo()` in C++, not in Java.